# I need make a process get more processor resources; changing its priority in Task Manager doesn't suit my needs. I need set a certain percentage

Tags: windows, resource-usage

English is not my native language; please excuse my typing errors and incorrect expressions.

I'm working on a Windows PC to decipher RSA, and need to make a process use more CPU resources. Advice from search engine(Baidu&Bing) is to change its priority in Task Manager, but it doesn't help. After I changed `python.exe` to High priority level, it still used only 30% of CPU. The other 70% was entirely a waste! How to manually set a certain percentage of CPU resources in Windows? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to manually set a certain percentage of CPU resources in Windows.

Windows doesn't have such a setting. Processes always run at "full speed" – as long as resources are available, each process always gets as much CPU time as it wants.

If you're seeing a process use less CPU time than is available, then that's because the process is *incapable* of using more. (For example, a program that works on files might be spending a lot of time waiting on data to be read, during which it can't do anything else.)

Note that in Windows Task Manager, "100% CPU utilization" means **all cores** of all CPUs should be in use. Your Python program is probably single-threaded, and a single thread is only capable of running on a single CPU core at once. Assuming you have a 4-core CPU, this means one core is at ~100% utilization while the other three cores are at ~0%, resulting in Windows showing only ~25% total.

(The OS cannot run the same task simultaneously on multiple CPUs – if it did, then all CPUs would just be doing exactly the same thing. That wouldn't make anything faster, it would just waste resources even more by duplicating work.)

So in order to make your program run faster, you'll need to rewrite it to be either multi-threaded or multi-process, distributing different parts of the work across all CPU cores. Python doesn't like threads much, so Python programs commonly use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module for this purpose.

> Advice from search engine(Baidu&Bing) is to change its priority in Task Manager, but it doesn't help

Priority levels only matter when all processes together want to use *more* than is available. When the system has enough resources available for all processes, there's nothing to prioritize as each process can already get as much as it needs.

Comment: It seems that being multi-threaded doesn't work for Python.

I tried the program(Python) again on a 4-core computer(Windows), and it truly used about 25% CPU. Then I rewrote it using threading module, but it still used only 25%. Being multi-threaded didn't change the number of cores it used.

`Python doesn't like threads much, so Python programs commonly use the multiprocessing module for this purpose.`

I'm not sure if it's the reason for it, and for some personal reasons I can't try multiprocessing module recently. I'll update the comment after I have a try. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the standard Python runtime has something called the "GIL" (global interpreter lock), which limits native-Python code to only 1 thread at a time – one thread has the lock, other threads are forced to wait until the lock is released. So only C-compiled modules (like numpy, I suppose) can _effectively_ use threads in Python, everything else unfortunately needs to use multiple processes. (Multithreaded programs in other languages also need to use locking, but they make it much more fine-grained, so threads need to wait less and have more opportunities to run.)